# Trigger an angular controller function on fancybox2 arrow click

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fancybox-2

I've created an ng-repeat loop of images with fancybox to display them. I've added an ng-click to trigger a controller function that defines the 'selected image' var and everything works just fine. I'm looking for a way to update the 'selected image' var when using the arrows to change image. I've tried using ng-change, but no luck so far.

```js
$scope.openPopUp = function(picture) {
  $scope.selectedPicture = picture;
};
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 mix" ng-repeat="picture in $parent.campaign.pictures">

  <a href="{{picture.facebookPicture.source}}" class="transparent-box campaign-picture-popup" rel="campaign-picture-popup" title="My title" ng-click="openPopUp(picture)">

    <div class="campaign_picturs_grid_col" style="background-image: url('{{picture.facebookPicture.source}}')">
      <div class="campaign_picture_user_info"></div>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Aren't you complicating things? you may not need an angular click binding for this. Just bind any class of your anchors to (or create an specific one for) fancybox an use the regular fancybox initialization `$(".myClass").fancybox()`